# How to insert using a control for MySQL and C#

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I need to know how to insert with mysql I have tried a couple different ways. I am using C# and Mysql here is an example of what I am trying to do(I already know this is incorrect but mybe you can get the idea of what I am trying to accomplish.)

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_test (name) VALUES(").append(TextBox1.Text.ToString()).append(")"),conn);

PS sorry for not using the code editor couldn't figure it out thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want something like this. I've written this from memory so there may be a few corrections needed to make it run.

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_test (name) VALUES (@name)";
var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", TextBox1.Text.ToString());
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Please click on "Accept". Thanks!